# Error: blog.Comment: (models.W042) Auto-created primary key used when not defining a primary key type, by default 'django.db.models.AutoField'

Tags: python, django

```
mysite-virtualenv) 10:43 ~/django-blog (master)$ ./manage.py migrate
System check identified some issues:
WARNINGS:
blog.Comment: (models.W042) Auto-created primary key used when not defining a primary key type, by default 'django.db.models.AutoField'.
        HINT: Configure the DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD setting or the BlogConfig.default_auto_field attribute to point to a subclass of AutoField, e.g. 'dja
ngo.db.models.BigAutoField'.
blog.Post: (models.W042) Auto-created primary key used when not defining a primary key type, by default 'django.db.models.AutoField'.
        HINT: Configure the DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD setting or the BlogConfig.default_auto_field attribute to point to a subclass of AutoField, e.g. 'dja
ngo.db.models.BigAutoField'.
users.Profile: (models.W042) Auto-created primary key used when not defining a primary key type, by default 'django.db.models.AutoField'.
        HINT: Configure the DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD setting or the UsersConfig.default_auto_field attribute to point to a subclass of AutoField, e.g. 'dj
ango.db.models.BigAutoField'.
```

Operations to perform:
Apply all migrations: admin, auth, blog, contenttypes, sessions, users
Running migrations:
No migrations to apply.

Comment: This warning happens with a newer version of Django with older code structure

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [Auto Created Primary Key [Django Doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/releases/3.2/#customizing-type-of-auto-created-primary-keys)

> To avoid unwanted migrations in the future, either explicitly set DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD to AutoField

Add `DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.AutoField'` in your `settings.py`

> If you want to set your field type per app basis then you can specify per app basis

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.AutoField'
    name = 'my_app'
```

> or even you can specify per model basis as

```
from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```